# RecyclerView Fit 5 items with different height and width using custom layout manager

Tags: android

First of all let me show you an image what i am trying achieve exactly :

[image]

Now as of above gif i need to build it with recyclerview.
Fit only 5 items at a time on screen.
Center and other 4 items will be scaled as shown in image.

I have tried with custom layout manager like below:

```
private val shrinkAmount = 0.3f
private val shrinkDistance = 1f

override fun scrollVerticallyBy(dy: Int, recycler: RecyclerView.Recycler?, state: RecyclerView.State?): Int {
        val orientation = orientation
        if (orientation == VERTICAL) {
            val scrolled = super.scrollVerticallyBy(dy, recycler, state)
            if (isScaleView()) {
                val midpoint = height / 2f
                val d0 = 0f
                val d1 = shrinkDistance * midpoint
                val s0 = 1f
                val s1 = 1f - shrinkAmount
                for (i in 0 until childCount) {
                    val child = getChildAt(i)
                    val childMidpoint = (getDecoratedBottom(child!!) + getDecoratedTop(child)) / 2f
                    val d = Math.min(d1, Math.abs(midpoint - childMidpoint))
                    val scale = s0 + (s1 - s0) * (d - d0) / (d1 - d0)
                    child.scaleX = scale
                    child.scaleY = scale
                }
            }
            return scrolled
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }
```

But i am getting output as follows:

[image: 1]

How can i achive exactly like above gif ?

Comment: https://github.com/bhaveshjabuvani88/CarouselEffect